# How to recover a deleted/restored App Catalog?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, disaster-recovery, app-catalog

Just because I wanted to change the app catalog url, and it's not editable, I decided to delete my app catalog and create it again.

When trying to create it again I got the Something went wrong page.

So I went to deleted sites and restored the app catalog.

All the web parts and extensions are there. Everything looks right.

However, the web parts vanished from my sites and now when I try to Add a the web parts again, I don't see anything from the app catalog.

Even redeploying everything I still can't see anything.

It's like my app catalog didn’t exist anymore.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It is sorted now. I just had to wait for a while and then Add the App Catalog again by creating a new one or entering the URL.

Apparently when you delete the app catalog it takes a while for that to process.

It was a long hour.